# Combining These Two Variables

Tags: php

I'm trying to combine these two:

```
$test1 = (isset($_GET["var1"]) && (isset($_GET["var2"]);
$test2 = test = !(strpos($_GET['var1'], '{') !== FALSE || strpos($_GET['var1'], '}') !== FALSE );
```

This is what I tried thats giving me an `unexpected ;` parse error parse error:

```
$test1 = (isset($_GET["var1"]) && 
!(strpos($_GET['var1'], '{') !== FALSE || 
strpos($_GET['var1'], '}') !== FALSE ) ||
(isset($_GET["var2"]) && 
!(strpos($_GET['var2'], '{') !== FALSE || 
strpos($_GET['var2'], '}') !== FALSE );
```

**EDIT**

what `$test1` does is checks to see if `var1` and `var2` are in the url
what `$test2` does is checks to see if `var1=` or `var2=` has `{` or `}` in the string.  I'm just trying to put this all into 1 variable

Comment: Just looking at your code, I'm not entirely sure what you want the end result to be.  Can you clear it up for us a bit, maybe write some psuedo code?

Comment: @SajanParikh ill explain it some more

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that makes more sense.

Comment: Sometimes it's better for the sake of clarity not to combine a whole load of conditionals into a single statement. Are you going to remember what this statement is doing in six months or a year from now?

Comment: this code could be factored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad parenthesis on line 1, and I assume you want that to be '$test', not 'test' on line 2:

```
<?php
$test1 = isset($_GET['var1']) && isset($_GET['var2']);
$test2 = $test = !(strpos($_GET['var1'], '{') !== FALSE || strpos($_GET['var1'], '}') !== FALSE );
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
$_GET['var1'] = "vvv";
$_GET['var2'] = "ddd";
$test1 = (isset($_GET["var1"]) && !(strpos($_GET['var1'], '{') !== FALSE || strpos($_GET['var1'], '}') !== FALSE ) || 
(isset($_GET["var2"]) && !(strpos($_GET['var2'], '{') !== FALSE || strpos($_GET['var2'], '}') !== FALSE )));

print $test1;
```

In short this is a mess. Don't do that you'll never recognize what it does after 6 month or so.

Answer (score -1):

This is a little verbose, but may change the way you're thinking about this.

`$test1` will have a truthy value if both vars are set. `test2` will have a truthy value if the either `{` or `}` exists in the string.

```
function testBrackets($string)
{
    $firstBracket = strpos($string, '{');
    $secondBracket = strpos($string, '}');

    if ($firstBracket == false and $secondBracket == false)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

if (isset($_GET['var1']) and isset($_GET['var2']))
{
    $test1 = true;
}

$test2 = 0;

if (isset($_GET['var1']))
{
    $test2 = $test2 + testBrackets($_GET['var1']);
}

if (isset($_GET['var2']))
{
    $test2 = $test2 + testBrackets($_GET['var2']);
}
```

Comment: I just looked at the return values for `strpos` and realized it will return 0 if the bracket was found at the first position, which renders this code unusable.  However, you should be able to tweak it to get around that.